# SSM parameters SAM local aws set up: unable to set properties to work in local

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-ssm, sam

people.
I have been trying to set up a project to test my lambdas in a local environment. We are using sam to mimic AWS resources and everything works pretty fine with one exception: for business reasons, I had to include SSM parameters. When we try to read the parameters using SAM with **sam local start-lambda ...** whatever, the lambda code is not able to recover the parameters. I know that AWS credentials are fine as I can connect to AWS, but we don't want to use real AWS services to do that, we want to pass, set, define; whatever you want to call it is fine, SSM parameters in my local environment and then use them with **sam local start-lambda** whatever, without AWS connection therefore we can use parameters for testing only in local.
I have read the following post, [How to access SSM Parameter Store from SAM lambda local in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322185/how-to-access-ssm-parameter-store-from-sam-lambda-local-in-node)
And this issue in github:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/616

It is mentioned that the way to do it is by using **--env-vars** but it is not working so far.
This is my template.

```
Parameters:
  IdentityNameParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler::handleRequest
      CodeUri: lambdaFunction
      Runtime: java11
      Timeout: 40
      Environment:
        Variables:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "keyid"
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "accesskey"
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-west-1"
          AWS_REGION: "us-west-1"
```

This is what I use to start the lambda
sam local start-lambda --host 0.0.0.0 -d 5859 --docker-volume-basedir /folderWithClasses --container-host host.docker.internal --debug --env-vars env.json

This is the env.json:

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "IdentityNameParameter": "admin"
  }
}
```

I guess there is no support to do this. If so, what's the point of having SAM to test it in local if you need AWS to actually test?

Any clue?

Comment: Okay, so basically you're trying to inject a local environment variable while invoking your lambdas locally. I see that you've already created a env.json file to inject values at runtime. Now I have two questions: 1) After running `sam local start-lambda` command are you actually invoking it using `aws lambda invoke --function-name "HelloWorldFunction" --endpoint-url "http://127.0.0.1:3001" --no-verify-ssl out.txt`. 2) If yes, what is the error that you are getting? What do you mean by not working so far? can you be more specific?

Comment: Are you not getting the value of this `System.getenv("IdentityNameParameter")` in your lambda?

Comment: The issue is that SSMClient is not able to get the parameters. It seems the remove server is reached, not the local one I was expecting to be created when using SAM local. 
Answering your question, yes, the lambda is invoked that way.

Comment: @SalvinoD'sa Thanks for your help, but that's not an SSM parameter, which is my current issue. I can get the environment property, but the code is trying to reach a SSM parameter through an ssmClient

Comment: ah gotcha. Can you not add an `environment` parameter to the template file which is set to local by default and when is set to local, can you not skip the code for fetching SSM parameters? You can override this parameter when you are deploying to stage and prod using sam configuration `.toml` file.

Comment: `Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
     Default: local`

Comment: Apologies for the delay, @SalvinoD'sa. No, the code is legacy code, we can't change it. Anyway, I think it is simply impossible to achieve what we wanted to do. The only alternative is to capture the request in a mock server and returns whatever we need to return...